# Setting the "finish" event on a Mojolicious/Minion::Job

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I am trying to have Minion jobs feed back to the Mojolicious web app upon completion (probably by posting a message to an API). The underlying idea here is then for the web app to feed back to the client that has uploaded/started the job.

I have tried doing this:

```
get '/' => sub {
    my $c = shift;
    my $id = $c->minion->enqueue('thing', [ qw/a b 1/, { foo => 'bar' } ]);

    my $job = $c->minion->job($id);

    $job->on(finish => sub ($job) {
              my $id   = $job->id;
              my $task = $job->task;
              $job->app->log->info(qq{Job "$id" was performed with task "$task"});
         });


    $c->render(template => 'index');
};
```

which doesn't work - I guess because the event is only emitted in the process performing the job, and the event does not get serialized and queued.

If I do this:

```
app->minion->add_task
    (thing => sub ($job, $c, $sub, @args) {
     $job->on(finish => sub ($job) {
              my $id   = $job->id;
              my $task = $job->task;
              $job->app->log->info(qq{Job "$id" was performed with task "$task"});
          });
          sleep 2;
     });
```

it works ok, but it means I have to add the event handling to every task - which adds complexity to the code.

Is there a way to avoid having to do this?

I am thinking of:

1. being able to set a default class for jobs (so that jobs are all of a subclass of Mojo::Job - for example `Minion::Job::WithFeedback`)
2. better yet, being able to inject roles into task creation (so that you can do `$c->minion->enqueue('thing', [ qw/a b 1/, { foo => 'bar' } ], { roles => qw/+WithFeedback +WithTimeout/);`

I know I could poll all jobs regularly and see what changed status - this is what the `Minion::Admin` plugin does - but I would like to see if there is a different way that doesn't require polling the database.

Is this possible? and while we're at it - is this a bad idea in and of itself?